# Find the center of an ellipse, given length of axes, a point on the ellipse, and slope of tangent through that point

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections

I have an ellipse with known major radius $r_x$ and minor radius $r_y$, aligned with the x- and y-axis.

[image]

Given a tangent point $T$ and the tangent angle $\alpha$, how do I calculate the center $C$ of this ellipse?

with a circle the equation is easy:

```
C_x = x - radius * cos ( tangent-angle - 90° )
C_y = y - radius * sin ( tangent-angle - 90° )
```

But for an ellipse this does not work.

(My goal is oriented hough transformation for ellipses)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, find the equation of the tangent line (using $\tan\alpha$). Then
use orthogonal affinity in the coordinate system, along the $y$-axis: 
$$(x,y)\mapsto (x,\frac y3)$$
Then the ellipse goes to a circle, tangent goes to tangent, and you can use your formula. Then multiply back $y$ coordinate of the result centrepoint by $3$.